# How to create screenshot viewer app?

Tags: android

I need to create a screen shoot reader app.
When user take screenshot, app automatically opens and show me taken screen, and I can do something what I need.

How to read screenshots every time when it taken?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You'd need to learn how to develop an app specifically for android. There are a few ways to do that, and a large amount of online resources to help you do so. There most likely won't be a tutorial to do exactly what you want, but there are a lot of tutorials on learning how to make android apps. There are plenty of websites that offer free and paid courses. I recommend some of the following:

[Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/topic:android) they've got over a hundred hours worth of Java courses, quizzes, code assignments, etc. and over 20+ individual Java courses. 
[Udemy](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837)
Google - there are many, many more sites to learn android development.